# Node-Red, Want to truncate results from BME280 Sensor

Tags: javascript, node-red

Node-Red question here.

I have hooked a BME280 sensor (Temp, Pressure, Humidity) up to my Raspberry Pi 3B for a side project I am doing in work.  I downloaded the BME280 Node and it connects without issue.  I then pipe the output through a JSON node to convert it to a standard that my dashboard uses (Freeboard dashboard).

The output is as follows:

{ temperature: 20.75, pressure: 1020.4576451979732, humidity: 43.76235104765547 }

**The question is:**

*How do I truncate the extra decimal places?  14 decimal places are killing my gauges!*

I've already tried using Math.Trunc in a function Node between the output and the Dashboard but... well, I'm a beginner coder so I could really do with a little help.

Apologies if this has already been asked before.
Mere

Edit:
The code I've already tried:

```
Math.Trunc("Pressure:", toFixed(2)); - not sure about this one
Math.Round("Pressure:" * 100) / 100;
```

I've also tried.

```
parseFloat("Pressure").toFixed(2) - found on this site
```

I guess this is where my inexperience really shows.

Comment: Show us the code you tried and somebody will help you fix it. (Edit the question to include it, don't try and add as a comment)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed()` function. For example if you want only 2 digits after the comma you can use `toFixed(2)`. For example

```
var t = 10.122345355
t.toFixed(2) // "10.12"
```

`toFixed` will convert it to string so you need to parse it as a float afterward

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in a function node:

```
var pres = msg.payload.pressure;
var temp = msg.payload.temperature;
var humidity = msg.payload.humidity;

msg.payload = {
  pressure: pres.toFixed(2),
  temperature : temp.toFixed(2),
  humidity: humidity.toFixed(2)
};

return msg;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tried this and it worked straight away.  And I'd also like to say thanks for helping me see the way I need to structure my code.

Answer (score 0):

Although this has been idle for a while, here is some more info  for the next person to come across it on how to parse the data from the BME280 in Node Red.
The data object delivered looks like this:

```
temperature_C: 24.54
humidity: 48.00285972066518
pressure_hPa: 1008.9618686461673
model: "BME280" 
heatIndex: 25.624424558111855 
dewPoint_C: 12.810600563041554 
altitude_M: 35.74196949170104
temperature_F: 76.172 
pressure_Hg: 29.79463137918758
```

Note that to get all this data you need to check the Extra Data box in the BME280 node otherwise you only get this:

```
temperature_C: 24.45
humidity: 48.38705227965796
pressure_hPa: 1009.0013733960975
model: "BME280"
```

Extract the data you want and truncate it in a function node like this:

```
var pres = msg.payload.pressure_hPa;
var temp = msg.payload.temperature_C;
var humidity = msg.payload.humidity;

msg.payload = {
  pressure: pres.toFixed(2),
  temperature : temp.toFixed(2),
  humidity: humidity.toFixed(2)
};

return msg;
```

Comment: Cool, I had no idea that this extra information was available.  Thanks again for updating this and I'm off now to update my project!

Comment: @Meremortal : For more details, go to the Node Red Discourse site. I posted a working flow there just today:
[link](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/bmp180-bmp280-i2c-nodes-cant-figure-it-out/5160/9)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite an old thread. Anyway, just so that it will benefit new comers, for Node-RED, you can use the following formatting at the gauge output to set 2 decimal places:

```
{{msg.payload | number:2}}
```